# Store file on server for a short time period

Tags: python, webapp2, temporary-files

What's the best way to name and store a generated file on a server, such that if the user requests the file in the next 5 minutes or so, you return it, otherwise, return an error code?  I am using Python and Webapp2 (although this would work with any WSGI server).

Comment: What are your concerns?  Do you want to just reduce/eliminate the possibility of duplicate names? Or do you also want unpredictability for security sake?

Comment: Security isn't important in this case.

Comment: So, are you looking for client or server code, or just a mechanism?   It's not clear from the question what level of detail you're looking for.

Comment: I was just sort of wondering what the standard way of storing files temporarily on a server was. The issues are: the files need to get unique names; the files have to be deleted after 5 minutes or so.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a client-created `UUID` on the server, and when the server stores it, send back an error (forcing a retry) to the client.   Under most circumstances, the UUID will be completely unique and won't collide with anything already stored.   If it does, the client can pick a new name and try again.  If you want to make this slightly better, wait a random number of milliseconds between retries to reduce the likelihood of collisions being repeated.

That'd be my approach to this specific, insecure, short-term storage problem.

As for removal, I'd leave that in the responsibility of the server to remove them at intervals, basically checking to see if any file is greater than 5 minutes old and removing them.   As long as in-process downloads leave the file open, it shouldn't interrupt.

If you want to leave the client in control, you will not have an easy way to enforce deletion when the client is offline, so I'd suggest keeping a list of the files in date order and delete them:

- in a background thread as necessary if you expect to be running a long time
- at startup (which will require persisting these to disk)
- at shutdown (doesn't require persisting to disk)

However, all of these mechanisms are prone to leaving unnecessary files on the server if you crash or lose the persistent information, so I'd still recommend making the deletion the responsibility of the server.

Comment: What about cleaning up the files? What's the best way to make sure they get deleted after a short period of time?